# можно ли сделать так чтобы мобильное устройство не передавала геолокационные данные приложениям которые установлены на нашем телефоне?

Tags: android, геолокация

можно ли сделать так чтобы мобильное устройство не передавала геолокационные данные приложениям которые установлены на нашем телефоне либо веб сайтам которыми пользуемся ?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Если говорите с точки зрения простого пользователя, это одно, если вы разработчик и делаете приложение, которое должно зарубить всем другим приложениям доступ к геоданным - совсем другое

Comment: с точки зрения пользователя я могу сделать так чтобы определенные приложение либо вообще никакие приложение не получили данные о геолокации ?

Comment: можете, удалите соотв. разрешение у приложения

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, вот варианты:

1. Тестовый источник геокоординат (в гуглоплее куча приложений mock location), правда в последних версиях Андроида надо иметь разрешение на это - ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION
2. XPosed + https://repo.xposed.info/module/com.fakemygps.android
3. Frida + https://codeshare.frida.re/@dzervas/android-location-spoofing/

Answer (score 2):

Ну и в дополнение к ответу с фиктивным местоположении, не стоит забывать про права доступа для приложений. Для каждого приложения индивидуально можно разрешить или запретить доступ к геоданным. Версии с 8 можно разрешить использовать геоданные только в тот момент, когда приложение открыто.11 версию Андроида вроде обещают научить давать приложению разовый доступ. Ну и в любой момент, даже когда приложение открыто, можно перейти в настройки, в раздел "Приложения" и изменить разрешения для этого рпиложения

Comment: в таком случае если отключить отправка геолокационных данных что будет получаться на стороне сервера приложения   ? данные IP?

Comment: @MariaWilson ничего. Приложение не сможет их получить, а значит слать ему нечего. Если программист криворукий или просто не опытный и не учел такого развития событий, то может и вылететь